# "Number of features of the model must match the input" while trying to predict new unseen data

Tags: python, numpy, text-classification

I trained a model on some Wikipedia articles divided by two categories (each category has 12 articles).

Below is how I created the model, trained it and pickled it:

```
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
import pickle
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
data = load_files(r'[...]review_polarity')
X, y = data.data, data.target
documents = []
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
stemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
for sen in range(0, len(X)):  
    # Remove all the special characters
    document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X[sen]))

    # remove all single characters
    document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document) 

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    document = document.lower()

    # Lemmatization
    document = document.split()

    document = [stemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in document]
    document = ' '.join(document)

    documents.append(document)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(X).toarray()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

with open('text_classifier', 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump(classifier, picklefile)
```

Then, I loaded the pickle file and tried to predict the classification for a new unseen article:

```
import pickle
import sys, os
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'text_classifier'), 'rb') as training_model:
    model = pickle.load(training_model)

with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'article.txt'), 'rb') as f:
    X = [f.read()]

documents = []
stemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()

for sen in range(0, len(X)):  
    # Remove all the special characters
    document = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(X[sen]))

    # remove all single characters
    document = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    document = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', document) 

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    document = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', document, flags=re.I)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    document = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', document)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    document = document.lower()

    # Lemmatization
    document = document.split()

    document = [stemmer.lemmatize(word) for word in document]
    document = ' '.join(document)

    documents.append(document)

tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1500, min_df=0, max_df=1.0, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(documents).toarray()

y_pred = model.predict(X)
print y_pred
```

I got the following error while calling the predict function:

*Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 10 and input n_features is 47*

It seems like the new article got a numpy array of 47 features, while the trained model works with arrays of 10 features. I'm not sure I understood this correctly, I'd be glad if you can help me understand better and make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Yes, you have interpreted the error message correctly.  Where is your attempt to trace that condition through your code?  At the very least, insert strategically-placed `print` statements to check the control and data flow of your work.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: I doubt tracing the error will help.  I suspect a fundamental misunderstanding of how training and prediction work.  There must be consistency between the features used in training, and features used in testing.  I think more study of `sklearn` documentation is in order.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely go over sklearn documentation. I may have not phrased it correctly, so my actual question is: TfidfVectorizer returned the same number of features for articles used as the train and test datasets, however it returned a different number of features for the new unseen article. How do I make sure the number of features match? Or better, how do I run my trained model on new unseen data (articles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I should have used the "transform" function instead of "fit_transform" for the new unseen data in order to keep the number of features the same.